# Version History Link Per Line Item

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript, versioning

**Scenario:** I would like to have a link per line item that takes the user directly to the version history for that item.

**Possible Solutions:** I was thinking of creating calculated column or a custom workflow all that I am not 100% sure will work.

Can anyone help me find a way to have direct link to version history per line item that is done automatically per link item without having to create the url manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with Client Side Rendering to instead of having to work with calculated columns or workflows.

Save this code to a new text document and save it with the name **renderVersionUrl.js** with the file extension .js

You will need to add a new column named **Version** (single line of text) to your list.

Upload it to your site collections Site Assets library and then apply it to your list web part using the JSLink property. (Add ~site/siteassets/renderVersionUrl.js).

This will render your column named "Version" to a hyperlink to the current items version history.

[image]

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
    return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
  }

  function init() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

     Templates: {
          Fields: {
              "Version": {
                  View: function(ctx) {
                    var itemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
                    var listId = ctx.listName;
                    var currSite = ctx.HttpRoot;
                    var versionUrl = "<a href='"+ currSite + "/_layouts/15/Versions.aspx?list=" + listId + "&ID=" + itemId + "'>Version History</a>"; // removed extra single quotes
                    return versionUrl;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/SiteAssets/renderVersionUrl.js"), init);
  init();

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The URL for the version history is:

```
/_layouts/Versions.aspx?list={GUID}&ID={itemid}
```

The workflow can build a string and update a column with the value. Remember if workflow will run on update item, it will create a new version so workflow on new item added might be better in terms of your requirement.

I think CSR might be a better way to achieve this rather than calculated field or workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Since the link to the versions page needs the item id, you'd need to do it through workflow when the item is created. The link looks like this:

https:///_layouts/15/Versions.aspx?list={7330FBF0-8603-41F2-B623-54F08E4835B7}&ID=563

You can build that through workflow.
Add a URL field to your list, called 'Version History' for example.

Build up a string variable in workflow that has both parts of the url - the link and the description. Make sure they are separated by a comma and a space:

**[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]**/_layouts/15/Versions.aspx?list={**7330FBF0-8603-41F2-B623-54F08E4835B7**}&ID=**[%Current Item:ID%]**, Version History

I'm not sure if you can get the GUID in the workflow, you might need to hardcode that.